# How do you fill the horizontal space in a line of flex children?

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

```css
.flex {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="child">
    <svg></svg>1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <svg></svg>2
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <svg></svg>3
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently the width of the child divs is determined by the size of the svg. I would like them to take up all available room in the row, so that there are three divs each taking 33% width. Can I do this with flexbox?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You do this simply by setting **flex-grow** on each flex-item's, in your case child's, css. Like this:

```
.child{
    background: lightblue;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

**Complete Example**:
(parent component needs to be display: flex, I removed the irrelevant wrap and justify-content)

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {background-color: powderblue;}
    h1   {color: blue;}
    .flex {
        display: flex;  
    }
    .child {
        background: orange;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px blue dashed;
    
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>How to fill horizontal space in line of flex children</h1>
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="child">
              <svg>
            </div>
            <div class="child">
              <svg>
            </div>
            <div class="child">
              <svg>
            </div>
          </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```